# vaadin grid height with pagination controls on mobile devices

Tags: css, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I'm using a vaadin-grid that is stacked upon a pagination toolbar (vaadin-grid-pagination) and the problem I'm having is that on mobile devices the pagination doesn't sit at the bottom of the viewport as the grid comes over it.

[image]

Ideally (disregard the pagination overflowing) it would look like this:

[image]

Now, through the Dev Tools inspector I was able to remove a position: relative property from the scroller and that made things behave as I want them to.

[image]

The problem is that I am unable to do this programatically... I tried using a custom css file with these contents:

```
:host() #scroller {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

and use it in the view that is building the grid:

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/grid-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
```

but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Not sure what the correct approach would be, if any.

Comment: You can inject custom styles using JS and override whatever is there, even if it's generated programatically to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify the internal styles of the components. There’s no guarantee that they will still behave/function correctly now or in the future. The `#scroller` selector is part of the private implementation details of the `<vaadin-grid>` component.

The only CSS selectors that you should style are `:host` and `[part]`, which can be combined with native pseudo-classes (`:hover`, etc.), pseudo-elements (`::before`, `::after`, etc.) and documented state attributes (`[disabled]`, `[active]`, etc.). Learn more about the [supported selectors](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/styling-components/#supported-css-selectors).

My suspicion is that the `height: 100%` on the `<vaadin-crud>` component is causing it to be too high. You should try using `flex: 1` on it instead.

Answer (score -1):

#1 Try setting the position value using !important ?

```
:host() #scroller {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute!important; /* add !important */
    }
```

#2 Otherwise like I suggested you can inject it using JS (here jQuery).

```
$('#scroller').css('position','absolute');
```

Making sure to insert that JS snippet as far down the load chain as possible.

Comment: #1 solution doesn't work and the #2 is not an option, unfortunately. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Maybe try a more specific selector ? i.e. `.my-list-view vaadin-crud vaddin-grid #scroller`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either.

Comment: can we know please where are the CSS styles causing issue generated or stored? The screenshot is cut off on the right, but Inspector should state a referall css file or some other info on the styles on the right.

Comment: The styles are generated by vaadin, a framework for building web-apps, so I'm not able to manually modify them.

Comment: I understand that, but still I would be curious to see what Inspector has to say about these styles, if you want me to continue helping you in the troubleshooting.

Comment: Targeting private CSS selectors is not recommended. The `#scroller` selector is part of the private implementation details of the vaadin-grid component.

Comment: @Jouni thanks for that, I was not aware of these best practices. To be really honest, and without trying to be a jerk, I am not a big fan of vaadin-grid or whatever pre-built stuff are related to it and I'm a proponent of not using such things, which is why, I guess, I have naively suggested good ol' targeting. I will keep that in mind however when trying to help pre-built-using-folks.